# Inline tag edits do not directly update post signature

Tags: bug, edits

When you edit a post with the <kbd>edit</kbd> button, the post is edited and the post signature is directly updated with the editor's signature:

[image]

However, when using the inline tag edit feature (10k+ user feature):

[image]

the post is edited but the post signature is only updated after a page reload.

I believe this is because after a 'real' edit, the page is reloaded automatically and when you edit inline it is not.

I don't know if this is easy to fix, but it seems a bug to me.

Comment: Yeah I guess this is a valid if minor irritation.

Comment: Huh, I had no idea the 'edit tags' link existed. Just never happened to hover my cursor over the exact spot needed to make it appear.

Comment: @MarkAmery I found out when I was reading about my new privileges when I hit 10k

Comment: @TimCastelijns Good name "post signature", I wonder how you came up with that! :)