# Long tags make things jump. Hide instead of suppress

Tags: bug, status-deferred, tags, design, user-interface

If you have 10k+ reputation, then you could reproduce it (it's the problem with the inline tag editor).

Go to [What is the most secure way of passing messages between an injected script and Google Chrome extension code/content script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38309087/1529630), which has long tags. Hover them.

The "edit tags" link appears, but does not fit in the line.

[image]

Then things start jumping. It doesn't look like good. Instead of `display` you should toggle `visibility`:

[image]

And also consider `display: inline-block` to force "edit" and "tags" to be in the same line.

[image]

Comment: This seems like a 10k+ world problem.

Comment: Ok, you can stop moving the pointer around... seriously!

Comment: OP changed the tags, I was excited to try (but not excited enough to edit the DOM)...

Comment: @Sam True. Now the date and the user signature move only horizontally.

Comment: Why does that link ever need to be hidden at all? That's really poor UI to hide options like that until you happen to mouseover close to them. Maybe it's to workaround the equally poor UI that the links do not look like links?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit As someone who [took a long time to discover the feature](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311487/inline-tag-edits-do-not-directly-update-post-signature#comment277954_311487), I agree.

Comment: You may want to edit the gifs to cross out the username because the meta effect

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I agree, I totally forgot about that feature until I read this post.

Comment: @Ferrybig eh..?

Comment: @Ferrybig given that OP links directly to the question I don't think removing the username from the GIFs will make a difference. Plus this issue isn't about the question, so I doubt the Meta Effect™ should be too strong here.

Comment: Btw, why do you have the vertical separators (`|`) between the links (share, edit, close, flag)? This design is un-existent for about one and a half a year, they do look [this way](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uNJJM.png) now.... Or is it browser-dependend? At least I haven't seen that weirdness neither with Safari, nor Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @nicael Ah, that's because I have a "StackOverflow Style Fixer" sheet which I probably found in meta.

Comment: The problem repros on Chrome latest in Windows 7 without any extensions/customs styles installed. Curiously, it repros without any visible wrapping of content to the next line. My screen is perfectly wide enough for all of the tags *and* the "edit tags" text to fit, yet I still get jumpiness, I suppose from wrapping padding to the next line?

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, for some reason there is `.edit-tags-wrapper { padding-right: 40px; }`. And `#question > table` is usually `7px` narrower than `#question`. So the padding makes the table grow to fill that available space.

Comment: Or instead of `visibility: hidden;`, maybe the upcoming `box-suppress: hide;` property! By the time this is implemented in 6 - 8 somethings, I'm sure it will have broad browser support ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "edit tags" link is now always visible (for users having the privilege), it is no longer faded in/out. It will usually appear to the right of the tags, or below them if the combined tag names are too long.

Also, it has been inline-block'd so that it is always in the same line.

**Update:**

Considering [how poorly has been this change received](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281912/136880), and that the "jumping" problem affects only a small percent of the questions, it has been undone. We'll try to figure out a better solution.

Comment: Isn't [feature discovery](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327730/long-tags-make-things-jump-hide-instead-of-suppress#comment365915_327730) important?

Comment: @Braiam It is. That will be considered when designing the "better solution".